# How to reset a StringJoiner to default state after usage

Tags: java, string

I am using StringJoiner to parse some data from a file in a Java project and I want to reset my StringJoiner variable to default state. **I don't want to nullify it and recreate it** in the loop l am running. I just **want to reset it** so l can reuse it. Is this even possible or should l just nullify it? I need your suggestions. Thanks

For example:

```
 StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ", "[","]");
 while(true){
      if(count == 100){
         //reset StringJoiner here

      } 
      else {
         sj.add("bla bla bla");
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the contract of the type and you will see that there is nothing for that.

So you can only save the result via `toString()` and then recreate it

```
String save = sj.toString();
sj = new StringJoiner(" ", "[","]");
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I did.

Comment: By "contract" do you mean documentation / API (just asking since I never heard of it)?

Comment: @pshemo indeed...publicly exposed methods (or functions) and properties ...aka documentation

Comment: Thanks for clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can not reset it, because of `prefix`, `delimiter` and `suffix` marked as final
and assigned in the constructor

```
    public StringJoiner(CharSequence delimiter,
                        CharSequence prefix,
                        CharSequence suffix) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(prefix, "The prefix must not be null");
        Objects.requireNonNull(delimiter, "The delimiter must not be null");
        Objects.requireNonNull(suffix, "The suffix must not be null");
        // make defensive copies of arguments
        this.prefix = prefix.toString();
        this.delimiter = delimiter.toString();
        this.suffix = suffix.toString();
    }
```

Comment: That is not blocking for the content...we could imagine a `clear`  method that just clear the string ...not pre/suffix and delimiter...

Comment: Yes I moved through the implementation and I found this